# TextView.setText outside of onCreate doesn't work

Tags: android, textview

I'm writing an android app where I want to modify a text view. When I'm editing it in the `onCreate()` method it works fine, but I want to modify it when the user click on the screen.
Now I know that the function for clicking on the screen is working, but the text doesn't get modified.

In the `onCreate()` method (works fine):

```
    main = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1_hidden_buttons);
    main.append(" " + newString);
```

Tap screen listener:

```
class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    // Clicking on the screen increases counter taps
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (busy)
                return true;
            busy = true;
        }

        main = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1_hidden_buttons);
        main.setText("Waiting for other players");

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("client", "ready");

            ConnectionHandler.send(json.toString());

            String serverResponse = ConnectionHandler.receive();

            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    OrderedButtonsActivity.class);
...
```

The app is waiting on `ConnectionHandler.receive()`.
After calling to modify the text, I call for a `wait()` method for the app, and after a while to another activity. For a short while (half a second or so) I could see the modified text.
Why does it happen and how can I fix it so that the text get modifed after clicking the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a couple of problems here:

1) You are trying to use `findViewById()` in a class that doesn't `extends` `Activity` (or any class that has a `findViewById()`.

2) It seems from your question that you are causing the UI `Thread` to sleep. Please do not do this. It is bad user experience to freeze the UI `Thread`. Unicorns and kittens will die for every millisecond the UI `Thread` is frozen.

The reason why it works if you do it inside `onCreate()` is because `Activity` has a `findViewById()`.

Comment: OK I will take that unicorn and kittens rescuing comment into consideration. But I tried to call a method from the activity class in `MyGestureListener` and it still didn't work. How can I make it work so that after clicking the screen the text will modify?


`public void setMainText(String text){
  main = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1_hidden_buttons);
  main.setText(text);
 }`

    `setMainText("Waiting for other players");`

Comment: OK forget about that, I changed it to run on another thread that waits for a server response, and now it works!

Unicorns and kittens are safe now and program is running, thanks!

Comment: _Unicorns and kittens will die for every millisecond the UI Thread is frozen._ -> Lol xd